# Rendering Diary entries for a user in Rails depending on created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following controller action inside a users_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
    @diary_entries = @user.diary_entries.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

This controller leads to this view Show.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-sm-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>

      </h1>
    </section>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.diary_entries.any? %>
  <table class="table table-dark">
    <h3 class="text-center">My Diabetes Diary </h3>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th scope="col">Time</th>
       <th scope="col">Bloodsugar</th>
       <th scope="col">Bread Units</th>
       <th scope="col">Injected Insulin</th>
       <th scope="col">Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

    <tbody class="diary_entries">

        <%= render @diary_entries %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

This view renders the _diary_entry.html.erb partial via (render @diary_entries)

```
<tr id="diary_entry-<%= diary_entry.id %>">
 <td> <span class="timestamp"><%= diary_entry.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %k:%M") %></span> </td>
  <td><span class="bloodsugar"><%= diary_entry.bloodsugar %></span></td>
 <td> <span class="carbohydrates"><%= diary_entry.carbohydrates %></span></td>
 <td> <span class="insulin"><%= diary_entry.insulin %></span></td>
 <td> <span class="comment"><%= diary_entry.comment %></span></td>
</tr>
```

My Question: Obviously I am rendering Diary Entries inside a table, which are previously retrieved from a Databse and belong to a user. Everything works fine. 
What I need now is that for every new day inside the diary I want a heading with the name of the day in one table row.
 
For that to happen I need some logic inside the rendering process of the partial which is checking the created-at attribute of the newly rendered entry and comparing it with the prevoiusly rendered entry. If the newly rendered entry has the date of a new day then, befoer rendering the new entry write a heading and after that render the entry.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Maybe I am wrong and this logic should be implemented somewhere else (Create action of the Diary or Javascript)???

Any help is higly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by iterating over the diary entries yourself and keeping track of the day for the current entry (rather than just `render @diary_entries`). Then when the day changes include your "day" row.

For example:

```
<tbody class="diary_entries">
  <% current_day = nil %>
  <% @diary_entries.each do |de| %>
    <% if current_day != de.created_at.jd %>
      <tr><td><%= de.created_at.strftime("%A") %></td></tr>
      <% current_day = de.created_at.jd %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render partial: 'diary_entry', locals: { diary_entry: de } %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I've used [`jd`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-jd) to keep track of the current day so that it'll cope across year/month/week boundaries.

Where it won't work as well is across pages. You'll always see a day at the top of a new page even if it isn't the first entry for that day (because earlier entries were on an earlier page). That might be desirable anyway or you could do a separate query to detect that situation.

Comment: I get a now method error for the julian day method in Rails. Do i need an additional gem for that I thought it is part of the ruby standard library.

Comment: It's in ruby 2 I think (1.9 might not have it). You can work out the current day other ways though if you need to. E.g. `de.created_at.to_i / (60*60*24)`.

Comment: i am using 2.4 so it should have it. But still no method error. i used `strftime(%d.%m)` instead

Comment: It seems `DateTime` has it but not `Time`. You could do `created_at.to_datetime.jd` but you've sorted it anyway :)